# Multi-branch network using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to build a multi-stream network in TF 2.0 using pre-trained sub-models on different physical features of the face. I have 3 different models trained on LeftEye, RightEye and Mouth regions. I am now wanting to load all these models into one network and train it to produce 1 output- say Gender. I'm using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices since I have image names with paths and Gender labels in a csv file.

Here's some snippets of code I have so far:

```
...
leftEye_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(leftEyeFiles), tf.constant(labels))).map(_parse_fn).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
rightEye_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(rightEyeFiles), tf.constant(labels))).map(_parse_fn).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
mouth_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(mouthFiles), tf.constant(labels))).map(_parse_fn).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)

valleftEye_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(valleftEyeFiles), tf.constant(vallabels))).map(_parse_fn).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
valrightEye_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(valrightEyeFiles), tf.constant(vallabels))).map(_parse_fn).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
valmouth_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(valmouthFiles), tf.constant(vallabels))).map(_parse_fn).batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
:
:
modelLeftEye=tf.keras.models.load_model('LeftEye')
modelRightEye=tf.keras.models.load_model('RightEye')
modelMouth=tf.keras.models.load_model('Mouth')

:
NUM_CLASSES=2
X0=modelLeftEye.layers[-3].output
ModelX0=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=modelLeftEye.input, outputs=X0)

X1=modelRightEye.layers[-3].output
ModelX1=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=modelRightEye.input,outputs=X1)

X2=modelMouth.layers[-3].output
ModelX2=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=modelMouth.input,outputs=X2)

combined=tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([ModelX0.output, ModelX1.output, ModelX2.output])
fc=Dense(16,activation="relu")(combined)
fc=Dense(NUM_CLASSES,activation='softmax',name='prediction')(fc)

ensembleModel=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[ModelX0.input,ModelX1.input,ModelX2.input],outputs=fc,name='ensemble_model')
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
ensembleModel.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((leftEye_train_data, rightEye_train_data,mouth_train_data))
history = ensembleModel.fit(dataset3.repeat(),
                    epochs=num_epochs,
                    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                    validation_data=dataset3.repeat(),
                    validation_steps=val_steps,
                    validation_freq=1),
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback]))
```

Obviously, the fit method throws the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model >is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), for inputs ['leftEye_0', 'rightEye_0', >'Mouth_0'] but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [, ]

What is the best way to prepare my input for the multi-stream network using tf.data.Dataset?